# On Wikipedia's "Spectrum of a ring" section

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I had some questions about the ["Spectrum of a ring" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology#Spectrum_of_a_ring) in the article about the Zariski topology. Assume for simplicity that $A=\mathbb C[x,y].$

> Thus, $V(S)$ is "the same as" the maximal ideals containing $S$.

(Above $V(S)$ means the set of complex  pairs $(a,b)$ such that $f(a,b)=0$ for all $f\in S$.) I understand it in the following sense: $$(a,b)\in V(S)\iff\forall f\in S, f(a,b)=0\iff \forall f\in S, f\in \ker(ev_{a,b})\iff S\subset (x-a,y-b)$$

But what exactly does "the same as" mean? I feel it's somehow related to $V'(S):=\{m\in MaxSpec(A): S\subset m\}$, but I can't formalize this.

Next, given $a\in A$, the article says that $a$ can be regarded as a function $Spec(A)\to Frac(A/I)$. Why do we need to consider $Frac(A/I)$ -- why not just $A/I$? What bad would happen if we considered $a$ as a map $Spec(A)\to A/I$?

> More generally, $V(I)$ for any ideal $I$ is the common set on which all the "functions" in $ I$ vanish, which is formally similar to the classical definition.

Common set of what? Do they mean the set $\{P\in Spec(A):\forall f\in I, f(P)=0\}$? Or what is meant here? The set $\{(a,b)\in \mathbb C^2: \forall f\in I, f(a,b)=0\}$ is also a "common set on which all the "functions" in $ I$ vanish", but if that's what is meant, then it's not clear how it is "formally similar to the classical definition" -- it **is** the classical definition.

> In fact, they agree in the sense that when $A$ is the ring of polynomials over some algebraically closed field $k$, the maximal ideals of $A$ are (as discussed in the previous paragraph) identified with $n$-tuples of elements of $k$, their residue fields are just $k$, and the "evaluation" maps are actually evaluation of polynomials at the corresponding $n$-tuples.

How to unpack this? And to begin with, what is the formal statement? Is it that there is a bijection between $\{(a,b)\in \mathbb C^2: \forall f\in I, f(a,b)=0\}$ and $\{P\in Spec\mathbb C[x,y]: I\subset P\}$? I guess this boils down to my very first question.

Comment: The 'same as' means that the map $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \operatorname{MaxSpec} \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is a homeomorphism. For a ring $A$ and a global section $f$ of $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$, i.e., $f\in A$, we regard $f$ as a function on $X$, taking the value $f \in k(P) = A_P/PA_P = \operatorname{Frac} A/P$ at $P \in X$. Thus, $f$ vanishes at $P$ if and only if $P \in V(f)$. This agrees with the classical version $f(a,b)$ via the bijection $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \operatorname{MaxSpec} \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: @LiuY The statement containing 'the same as' involves $S$, but the map $\mathbb C^2\to MaxSpec \mathbb C[x,y]$ doesn't say anything about $S$. Or am I misunderstanding something? As for the other parts, frankly I would prefer not going beyond the scope of that article on the Zariski topology (it doesn't mention "sections", localizations at $P$)... I was hoping that those statements can be understood/explained by having only the terminology used in that article at one's disposal.

Comment: The bijection $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \operatorname{MaxSpec} \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ sends $V(S)$ to $V'(S)$ (in your notation). For the second part, then please let me ask, what does "$f(P)$" mean by an $f \in I$ and $P \in \operatorname{Spec} A$?

Comment: Note that $MaxSpec \mathbb{C} ≠ Spec \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You find a discussion on the question "Why do we need prime ideals in the spectrum of a ring?" here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728255/why-do-we-need-prime-ideals-in-the-spectrum-of-a-ring/4208275#4208275

Comment: @LiuY $f(P)$ means $f \text{ mod } P$ (here I used the fact that comes later in the "Spectrum of a ring" section, although I still don't understand why the codomain of $f$ regarded as a function should be $Frac(A/I)$ instead of just $A/I$).

Comment: @user538518 $Frac (A/I)$ is not available if $I$ is not a prime ideal. The right one is $Frac (A/P)$. In the language of locally ring space $(X, O_X)$, an element $f \in O_X(U)$ is a function defined on $U$, and the germ $f_x$ at a point $x \in X$ takes the "value" $f_x \operatorname{mod} m_x \in O_{X,x}/m_x.$ This is a "natural" definition when $(X, O_X)$ is associated to a real/complex manifolds. Now we bring this to schemes, we get $O_{X,x}/m_x = Frac(A/P)$.