# Meaning of an element "vanishing" on $V(I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading a question on Vakil's algebraic geometry notes and I am confused by a particular term (exercise 3.4.J in the [November 17, 2018 draft](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) on page 118).

Suppose $I\subset B$ is an ideal where $B$ is a commutative ring. We are asked to "Show that $f$ vanishes on $V(I)$ if and only if $f\in\sqrt{I}$".

My question is what does it mean for $f\in B$ to
vanish" on $V(I)$? I know we sometimes say an element of a ring vanishes at a prime ideal if it is contained in the prime ideal. However, what does it mean in this context?

Comment: [There are two commonly understood meanings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3715926/confusion-about-what-it-means-for-a-section-to-vanish-on-a-subscheme/3716115#3716115). Please include a precise reference so we can give more precise help.

Comment: The reference is the most recent version of the notes http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/ exercise 3.4.J on page 118

Comment: @Randall It's on page 118. I will make the edit.

Comment: Doesn’t the second paragraph in the opening of 3.4 explain this?

Comment: @Randall Not entirely. At least it's not clear to me. Here he's saying that "vanishing at a point" is equivalent to being "contained in a prime". He doesn't mention anything about vanishing at $V(I)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means $f$ belongs to all prime ideals in $\operatorname{Spec}B$ that contain $I$. As the intersection of all these prime ideals is the root of the ideal $I$…

Comment: Huh, so then the "proof" more or less follows by the fact that $\sqrt{I}$ is the intersection of all prime ideal containing $I$.

Comment: Yes. The main work consists in the proof of this algebraic result. The rest is a translation in the language of algebraic geometry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Vaki'l book, but usually $f=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a polynomial over a field $k$ and $V(I)$ is a subset of $\mathbb A^n=k^n.$ Then all this means is $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0$ for all $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)\in V(I).$

---

Edit by tkf:

Although not answering the question, this does provide intuition for the correct answer.  We may regard elements of $\mathbb A^n$ as primes in the ring $B=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Specifically $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ corresponds to the prime $p_a=\langle x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n\rangle$.  Then in this case given $f\in B$, we have equivalent statements: $$f\in p_a \iff f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0.$$

If we let $V_I\subseteq \mathbb A^n$ consist of elements $a$ such that $g(a)=0$ for all $g\in I$, then for all $a\in \mathbb A^n$:$$p_a\supseteq I  \iff a\in V_I.$$

For a general commutative ring $B$, the notions on the right which this user used to define $f$ vanishing on $V_I$ do not make sense, but the notions on the left do, leading to the correct explanation given by @Bernard.

Comment: $B$ here is just a general ring, not necessarily a polynomial.

Comment: Got it. Then disregard this answer.

Comment: I would recommend that you delete your answer to avoid any confusion, however, it is ultimately up to you. To people in the low-quality posts queue: answers should not be removed due to technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

Comment: @TobyMak I tried to put the answer into context with the correct answer, so that it may be useful for someone who comes across this post while googling an explanation.  Do you still recommend deletion?

Comment: After the edit by tkf, I think your answer is perfectly fine as it is. No, I do not recommend deletion.